# what is defference between django rest framwork's 'serializer' and 'serializer fields'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

The serializer of django rest framework converts the model data to JSON format and validates incoming data
 Check function. The functions of the serializer fields are to convert values ​​and data types and to validate input values. I think it looks the same, but I wonder what the difference is.

Comment: The relation is about the same as between a Model and its Fields.

Comment: @Klaus D thanks for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the definition of the `Serializer` class in the source code you will see that it is a descendant of `Field`.

`class BaseSerializer(Field):`

`class Serializer(BaseSerializer):`

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py

Aside from the implementation in the code `Serializer`s are complex fields which can have subfields inside. All other fields are used to serialize/validate basic data (numbers, stings, list of numbers/strings etc.) while `Serializer`s are used to serialize/validate objects which are composed of other fields.